# SQL Update Statement -- Why does this work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I wrote a query that works and accomplishes what I want, but I can't figure out why the logic is working. I can't share the exact tables because the information is sensitive but I'll recreate below.

Table_A has three columns:

```
Employee_ID, 
Condition, 
B_Confirmed_Flag
```

Table_B has two columns:

```
Employee_ID, 
Condition
```

My goal was to write an update statement that updates B_Confirmed_Flag in Table_A to 1 whenever the Employee_ID -> Condition combination exists in Table_B.

**UPDATE STATEMENT:**

```
 UPDATE TABLE_A
    SET B_Confirmed_Flag = 1
    FROM TABLE_A
    WHERE TABLE_A.Condition IN (SELECT TABLE_B.CONDITION
                                FROM TABLE_B
                                WHERE TABLE_B.EMPLOYEE_ID = TABLE_A.EMPLOYEE_ID)
```

This update statement seems to work, but I'm confused on the logic. I would've thought that with this update statement I would've needlessly flagged certain rows where multiple Employee_ID's in Table_B have the same value in the Condition column. However, the query is working for me.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the primary keys?

Comment: @paparazzo employee_ID is the primary key in both tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer how it works, break down the query similar to this:
For each record in Table A, subquery all records from Table B where the employee id matches.  Then if the record in table A has Condition that is present in the subquery the update happens.  Effectively giving you a join condition on both employeeID and Condition.

As others have answered, rewriting your query will be easier to read and may perform better.

Comment: Great explanation in English, easy to understand. Marked correct!

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have dummy data like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #table_A (Employee_ID INT, 
Condition VARCHAR(1), 
B_Confirmed_Flag BIT
)

CREATE TABLE #table_B (Employee_ID INT, 
Condition VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #table_A (Employee_ID, Condition, B_Confirmed_Flag)
VALUES 
(1, 'A', 0),
(2, 'A', 0),
(3, 'A', 0),
(4, 'B', 0),
(5, 'B', 0),
(6, 'B', 0),
(7, 'B', 0)

INSERT INTO #table_B (Employee_ID, Condition)
VALUES 
(1, 'A'),
(3, 'A'),
(5, 'B'),
(6, 'B')
```

If you run these two queries and turn on execution plans, you will see the difference.

```
select * 
FROM #TABLE_A
WHERE #TABLE_A.Condition IN (SELECT #TABLE_B.CONDITION
                            FROM #TABLE_B
                            WHERE #TABLE_B.EMPLOYEE_ID = #TABLE_A.EMPLOYEE_ID)
select * 
FROM #TABLE_A
WHERE #TABLE_A.Condition IN (SELECT #TABLE_A.CONDITION
                            FROM #TABLE_A
                            WHERE #TABLE_A.EMPLOYEE_ID IN (1,4))
```

The first one is yours and the second is a sample. It sounds like you are expecting your query to work like the 2nd one here. If the IN part of your query should return values that should update all records in table_A, why doesn't it? If you examine the execution plan and look at the nested loop predicate, you can see that your query is looking at the condition as well as the employee ID. That is why the update only updates the employees it finds in table B as well as their condition.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Got it that makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It works because update is processed row by row

This should be more efficient

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET B_Confirmed_Flag = 1
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE exists ( SELECT 1 
                 FROM TABLE_B
                 WHERE TABLE_B.EMPLOYEE_ID = TABLE_A.EMPLOYEE_ID 
                   and TABLE_B.Condition   = TABLE_A.CONDITION 
             ) 
 and (B_Confirmed_Flag <> 1 or B_Confirmed_Flag is null)
```

if those are pk then

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET B_Confirmed_Flag = 1
FROM TABLE_A
JOIN TABLE_B
  ON TABLE_B.EMPLOYEE_ID = TABLE_A.EMPLOYEE_ID 
 and TABLE_B.Condition   = TABLE_A.CONDITION 
 and (B_Confirmed_Flag <> 1 or B_Confirmed_Flag is null)
```

Comment: The question is "Why does this work?" not how to rewrite it.

Comment: Do you know why my code is working? It looks like logically it shouldn't work since I'm not stating explicitly "Where Table_A.Condition = Table_B.Condition" but it does work